# Can't select between Maven installations in Netbeans

Tags: java, windows, maven, netbeans

I have a strange problem with Netbeans 7/8 on Windows 7, no matter how often i reinstall Netbeans I can't choose between Maven installations / home neighter do I see any Maven Home Option in the Dropdown (Tools -> Options -> Java -> Maven)

I found the installation path of the embedded Maven inside the netbeans installation path and I edited the settings.xml so i can use the embedded Maven.

But I need more than one Maven installations! Please Help!!!

[image: here should be an image]

Answer (score 0):

That would be a bug that you should report at https://netbeans.org/bugzilla (component project, subcomponent maven). Along with details of your setup.